# How to enter 4 numbers in EditText and seprate it as four variables in code ? Android beginner

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi I just started android development, And I want to know how I can separate the 4 numbers I enter in a single edittext in order as four variables ? Since I'm a noob your help means a lot for my training.

I want to put it in a array but not sure how to do it.

```
    String[]num =new  String[4];
String tt = number4ed.getText().toString();

for(int i = 0; i < num.length;i++){

}
```

Comment: I tried to add the string from the edit text in the array , however, I'm not sure if it's the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
String[] num = new String[4];
    String tt = number4ed.getText().toString();
    char[] arr = tt.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        String number = String.valueOf( arr[i]);
        num[i]=number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

layout file

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="11 12 13 14" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

The Java class : Main1.java

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main1 extends Activity{


private EditText edit;


@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

    String my = edit.getText().toString();

    Log.d("kushal","1:"+my);

    String my1[] = my.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < my1.length; i++) {
        Log.d("kushal",i+":"+my1[i]);
    }
   }
}
```